# Add quantile to MonteCarlo Simulation results in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, risk-analysis

I created a Monte Carlo Simulation for a single stock portfolio and would like to calculate and ideally display certain quantiles. For instance, in my example i have 1000 runs and would like to calculate the 95% quantile of the result (t252).

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import quandl

style.use('ggplot')

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'dnyYEnFxwxxxxxxxxxxx'


prices = quandl.get(dataset='WIKI/AAPL',start_date='2000-01-01',end_date='2010-12-31')['Close']
returns = prices.pct_change()
last_price = prices[-1]

num_simulations = 1000
num_days = 252

simulation_df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(num_simulations):
    count = 0
    daily_vol = returns.std()

    price_series = []

    price = last_price * (1  + np.random.normal(0, daily_vol))
    price_series.append(price)

    for y in range(num_days):
        if count == 251:
            break
        price = price_series[count] * (1  + np.random.normal(0, daily_vol))
        price_series.append(price)
        count += 1


    simulation_df[x] = price_series

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(simulation_df)
plt.axhline(y = last_price, color = 'r', linestyle = '-')
plt.show()
```

Can someone tell me what the best way to go is? I had a go at the Pandas quantile function but did not get far unfortunately.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas quantile function is the way to go. If you want 252 values (i.e. .95 quantile of each day) you can use the axis parameter:

```
simulation_df.quantile(.95, axis=1)
```

If you just want a quick overview, transpose and use the describe function:

```
simulation_df.T.describe(percentiles=[.95, .75, .5, .25, .05])
```

Comment: Many thanks, I got the structure wrong.. Do you happen to know if such a level can be added to a chart, say the 5% quantile at t252?